# Why we recite Bismillah two times in surah Namal?

Tags: quran, history

I know that we recite bismillah two time in surah namal but i want to know that what is the reason behind reciting second time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do I say "bismillah" in 2nd rakat?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/51274/do-i-say-bismillah-in-2nd-rakat)

Comment: Reciting it at the beginning of the surah is not mandatory as there's no consensus that it is part of the qur'an.

Answer (score 1):

The other *Bismillah* is part of the narrative of the Surah. Suleman عليه السلام is informed of the Kingdom of Saba ([verses 22-26](https://legacy.quran.com/27/22-26)) and he sends a letter to their Queen ([verse 28](https://legacy.quran.com/27/28)) which reads:

> إنه من سليمان وإنه **بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم**
>
> ألا تعلوا علي وأتوني مسلمين
>
> Indeed, it is from Solomon, and indeed, it reads: '**In the name of
>   Allah, the Entirely Merciful, the Especially Merciful**,
>
> Be not haughty with me but come to me in submission [as Muslims].'
>
> <sup>— [Quran 27:30-31](http://legacy.quran.com/27/30-31)</sup>

Basically the letter begins with *Bismillah*, and we are repeating the contents of the letter.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is **Solomen** sent an invatation to a Queen That letter starts in bismillah